# Interpolating between values of a DataArray

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, interpolation, python-xarray

*I would like to know what is the most efficient, or most elegant way to interpolate between values of a DataArray.* Ideally, this should be usable for arbitrary number of dimensions, but good solutions for low dimensions such as 2D and 3D would also be useful.

I am aware of the `'method'` keyword for the `sel` method and have the feeling that is going to be part of the answer, but I find the solution I came up with not to be very elegant. (I do not know about its efficiency.) Let me illustrate this solution:

```py
>>> import xarray as xr
>>> arr = xr.DataArray([[12, 32], [14, 34]],
...                    dims=['x', 'y'], coords={'x': [1, 3], 'y': [2, 4]})
>>> arr
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 2)>
array([[12, 32],
       [14, 34]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 1 3
  * y        (y) int64 2 4
>>> arry = ((arr.sel(x=2, method='pad') * (2 - arr.coords['x'].sel(x=2, method='pad')) +
...          arr.sel(x=2, method='bfill') * (arr.coords['x'].sel(x=2, method='bfill') - 2)) /
...         (arr.coords['x'].sel(x=2, method='bfill') - arr.coords['x'].sel(x=2, method='pad')))                                                                                              
>>> arry                                                                                                                                                                                       
<xarray.DataArray (y: 2)>                                                                                                                                                                      
array([ 13.,  33.])                                                                                                                                                                            
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) int64 2 4
>>> ((arry.sel(y=3, method='pad') * (3 - arry.coords['y'].sel(y=3, method='pad')) + 
...   arry.sel(y=3, method='bfill') * (arry.coords['y'].sel(y=3, method='bfill') - 3)) /
...  (arry.coords['y'].sel(y=3, method='bfill') - arry.coords['y'].sel(y=3, method='pad')))
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(23.0)
```

For why I find this approach sub-optimal: the calculation of arry could include a large number of unnecessary arithmetic operations when the length of the y index is large (and not just 2 as in this toy example).

Comment: Just to be clear, you would like to interpolate to a point along a dimension that does not exist yet, correct?

Comment: @jhamman: I don't think so (I may be misunderstanding your question); I want to interpolate at coordinate points that do not exist; in the example above `(x, y) == (2, 3)`.